# Adding header's name for dataset in kbl

Tags: r

When I use kbl in r markdown, sometimes the header's name lost. Look the pic, the head column's names are all "x" instead of its original one (df3:"No."variable","p-value"; df.gini.sort:"variable","gini score. Could anyone help to figure out how to fix that? Thanks~~!

[image]

Comment: What is `df3` and `df.gini.sort`?.  If both of them are dataframes, when you do `c`, it becomes a named list of vectors i.e. `c(head(iris), head(mtcars))` check the output.  Perhaps you meant `rbind(df3, df.gini.sort)` ?

Comment: @akrun, they are both dataframe. One has 3 variables (the first 3 cols), one has two (the last two). I want to present them side by side like the pics meanwhile keep all their col's names

Comment: In that case you need `cbind` instead of `c` i.e. `cbind(df3, df.gini.sort)` assuming both have same number of rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `cbind` instead of `c` as `c` will concatenate the `data.frame` to a named `list` of vectors (`data.frame` - is a `list` of vectors/columns of equal length with additional attribute).  Here, we assume both the datasets to have the same number of rows

```
library(kableExtra)
kbl(cbind(df3, df.gini.sort))
```

If we are using `c`, then wrap with `data.frame` afterwards

```
kbl(data.frame(c(df3, df.gini.sort)))
```